# Calling function in App.js from another component

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to ReactJS and want to use this library: https://github.com/teodosii/react-notifications-component

It states that "You must place ReactNotificationsComponent component at the root level of the application in order to work properly, otherwise it might conflict with other DOM elements due to the positioning."

I followed the usage guide, but I'm not sure how to call the `addNotification` function from a child component.

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactNotification from "react-notifications-component"

import Header from './components/Header'

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.addNotification = this.addNotification.bind(this)
    this.notificationDOMRef = React.createRef()
  }

  addNotification() {
    this.notificationDOMRef.current.addNotification({
      title: "Awesomeness",
      message: "Awesome Notifications!",
      type: "success",
      insert: "top",
      container: "top-right",
      animationIn: ["animated", "fadeIn"],
      animationOut: ["animated", "fadeOut"],
      dismiss: { duration: 5000 },
      dismissable: { click: true }
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ReactNotification ref={this.notificationDOMRef} />
        <Header />
      </div>
    )
  }
}



export default App
```

Header.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import logo from "../assets/images/logo/logo-light.png"
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, NavLink, Switch } from "react-router-dom"
import Home from '../pages/Home'
import Apply from '../pages/Apply'

export default class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Route render={({ location }) => (
            <header id="navbar-spy" className="header header-1 header-dark header-fixed">
                <nav id="primary-menu" className="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
                    <div className="container">
                        <div className="navbar-header">
                            <button type="button" className="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                                <span className="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                <span className="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span className="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span className="icon-bar"></span>
                            </button>
                            <img className="logo-light" src={logo} alt="Logo" draggable="false" />
                        </div>

                        <div className="collapse navbar-collapse pull-right" id="navbar-collapse-1">
                            <ul className="nav navbar-nav nav-pos-right navbar-left">
                                <li className="">
                                    <NavLink to="/" className="menu-item">Home</NavLink>
                                </li>

                                <li className="">
                                    <NavLink to="/apply" className="menu-item">Apply</NavLink>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>

            </header>
            )}
          />

          <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
          <Route path="/apply" exact component={Apply} />
        </div>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}
```

When you click the "Apply" link, it loads the `Apply` component. In that component, they can receive an error/success notification. From that component is where I want to be able to tell the ReactNotification in App.js what title, message, and type to render. How can I communicate from Apply.js to App.js?

Answer (score 3):

You can pass the `addNotification` function to your `Header` component:

```
<Header addNotification={this.addNotification} />
```

And you can continue to pass it down to other child components, until you are ready to call it.

Comment: would I put this in my header component? Or in app.js?